# Selecting a value from a drop down menu via Javascript [Google accounts creation page]

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, firefox, drop-down-menu

Below is snippets of code I have put together to randomly automate a selection of a birth month via the google accounts creation page.

The months are generated via a drop down list and have appropiate id's i.e 1=January 2=February etc.

I have tried changing my values in myArray to actual months (January,February etc) with no luck aswell.

Where have I gone wrong? Or is this not how it's done?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```html
//Get select object
var objSelect = document.getElementById("BirthMonth");
var myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

//Set selected
setSelectedValue(objSelect, "myArray");

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectObj.options[i].text== valueToSet) {
            selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var objSelect = document.getElementById("BirthMonth");
```

The `objSelect` DOM element has no `options` array to access like you are using.

```
var myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];
```

The month elements actually have Ids with values `:1` - `:9` and then `:a` - `:c`.

The hidden field that contains the selected month value is `HiddenBirthMonth`. The caption element for the month field has an Id of `:0`, and that needs to be set to the corresponding month caption. We can get that from the `textContent` property of the month element.

The annoying bit is the fact that the individual month elements aren't rendered until you click the drop-down list. To get around this, I created a function to trigger the `mousedown` event twice quickly, before continuing.

**Working Solution:**

```
function setRandomBirthMonth() {
    var hiddenMonthField = document.getElementById("HiddenBirthMonth");
    var selectedMonthCaption = document.getElementById(":0");
    var monthIds = [':1', ':2', ':3', ':4', ':5', ':6', ':7', ':8', ':9', ':a', ':b', ':c'];
    var randomMonth = monthIds[Math.floor(Math.random() * monthIds.length)];

    // month options don't render until a 'mousedown' event, so let's simulate it
    if (document.getElementById(randomMonth) == null) forceRenderOfMonths();
    var selectedMonth = document.getElementById(randomMonth);

    hiddenMonthField.value = randomMonth;
    selectedMonthCaption.setAttribute("aria-posinset", randomMonth);
    selectedMonthCaption.textContent = selectedMonth.textContent;

    function forceRenderOfMonths() {
        var select = document.getElementsByClassName("jfk-select")[0];
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

        clickEvent.initEvent("mousedown", true, true);
        select.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        clickEvent.initEvent("mousedown", true, true);
        select.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
}

setRandomBirthMonth();
```

Comment: Hi Gideon, the working solution you have provided works flawlessly in chrome. However what adjustments would be needed to be made to have this work on a firefox browser. As I tried in firefox and it works 9/10 of the way and requires a manual off click for the month to be selected. Seems like the mouse events would be different for firefox.

Comment: @BradleyMcKinnon Made a small modification. It should work fine Chrome, FireFox and Safari now. Not tested on others.

Comment: Working as you described! Thanks for your help, greatly appreciated.